# PHP- Sorting multidimensional array into another by range of numbers

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that I get from DB. Array has a number of views by each hour that is logged in the DB as a view, and it looks like this:

```
array:11 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
         "hour" => 0
         "views" => 1
         ]
    1 => array:2 [▼
         "hour" => 1
         "views" => 1
         ]
    2 => array:2 [▼
         "hour" => 4
         "views" => 1
         ]
    ...and so on
    ]
```

I need to make a new array that will contain number of views for range of 2 hours. So for example from the array shown above I would like to get an array with, number of views for time between 0-2, that would 2, and for 2-4, would be 0 in this case, and so on.

Comment: Why *and for 2-4, would be 0* if `2 => array:2 [▼
         "hour" => 4
         "views" => 1`

Comment: Because that view would be counted for range 4-6, and since the views for 2 and 3 are missing, I need to put 0 for that range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in Mysql query:

```
select floor(hour/2) range, sum(views) sum 
   from thetable 
 group by range
```

Comment: Do you know maybe how would I do that query in laravel preferably, my table from which I am pulling those views, has a column created_at which is a timestamp that looks like this: 2016-05-03 22:41:59

Comment: how do you receive "hour" => 0 from timestamp ?

Comment: I have this kind of query now:     View::groupBy('hour')
                            ->orderBy('hour', 'ASC')
                            ->get([
                                DB::raw('Hour(created_at) as hour'),
                                DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"')
                            ])->toArray();

Comment: i never saw laravel. but think it will be `View::groupBy('range') ->orderBy('range', 'ASC') ->get([ DB::raw('floor(Hour(created_at)) as range'), DB::raw('COUNT(*) as "views"') ])->toArray();`

Comment: Thanks, I think these is probably the best solution to do everything in the query. Thanks!

Comment: glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use a foreach to create a new array.

```
<?php


$your_array = [0 => [
         "hour" => 0,
         "views" => 4
         ],
    1 => [
         "hour" => 1,
         "views" => 12
         ],
    2 => [
         "hour" => 4,
         "views" => 1
         ],
    3 => [
         "hour" => 2,
         "views" => 9
         ],
    4 => [
         "hour" => 21,
         "views" => 19
         ]
         ];   



foreach ($your_array as $value){
    for($i=0;$i<=22;$i=$i+2){
    $j=$i+2;
    if($value['hour']>=$i && $value['hour']<$j){
        isset($result[$i.'-'.$j])?$result[$i.'-'.$j]+=$value['views']:$result[$i.'-'.$j]=$value['views'];
    }
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Yes but that way I need to do if statments for all time ranges, since I don't have only the ones that I listed above in the question, I am hoping for some more elegant solution to it.

Comment: you must define exactly what you want.You want every two hours ranges for all day in 24 hour format?

Comment: Ok I updated the answer that would sum the views for every two hours "0-1","2-3","3-2",....,"22-23"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
$arr = [0 => [
         "hour" => 0,
         "views" => 1
         ],
    1 => [
         "hour" => 1,
         "views" => 1
         ],
    2 => [
         "hour" => 4,
         "views" => 1
         ]];    

foreach($arr as $row)
{
    if($row['hour'] >= 0 && $row['hour'] <= 2)
    {
        $newArr['0-2'] = isset($newArr['0-2']) ? ($newArr['0-2'] + 1) : 1;
    }
    if($row['hour'] > 2 && $row['hour'] < 4)
    {
        $newArr['2-4'] = isset($newArr['2-4']) ? ($newArr['2-4'] + 1) : 1;
    }
}
print_r($newArr);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0-2] => 2
)
```

Comment: Same as for the other answer, these way I need to do if statments for all time ranges and since I don't have only the ones that I listed above in the question, I am hoping for some more elegant solution to it.